# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting while execute SQL

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am getting the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "create_user.py", line 18, in create_user
>       c.execute(create_user_sql, user_id)
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

while i run this

```
import psycopg2
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_id=sys.argv[1]
    c = conn.cursor()
        create_user_sql="create user %s with password 'Xx12345678' in group test_group;"
        c.execute(create_user_sql, user_id)
```

I have tried to use `%user_id` instead. Any idea?

Comment: pass tuple: `c.execute(create_user_sql, (user_id,))`

Comment: Tried `[user_id]`, `(user_id,)`,`[user_id,]` still getting the same error

Comment: per chance, is the password provided contains percent chars?

Comment: yup, i ended up doing it the following way `create_user_sql="create user "+ user_id + " with password 'Xx12345678' in group test_group;"
        print (create_user_sql)
        c.execute(create_user_sql)` which is not the best way, but it work

Comment: `c.execute(create_user_sql % user_id)` would be better in that case.

Comment: `c.execute(create_user_sql % user_id)` works. Thanks